# wiered behaviour by chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, rendering, clock

the code works fine with Microsoft Edge but in Chrome the Seconds Hand gets back after a second. It seems like the secondHand variable does not get affected when first time increment happens. But whenever I do debug using dev tools it's been perfectly run. Is there any browser issues not to render as expected ?

```js
    let hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour');
    let minuteHand = document.querySelector('.minute');
    let secondHand = document.querySelector('.second');

    let intialHourHandPosition = (new Date().getHours())*30-90;
    let intialMinuteHandPosition = (new Date().getMinutes())*6-90;
    let intialSecondHandPosition = (new Date().getSeconds())*6-90;

    hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${intialHourHandPosition}deg)`;
    minuteHand.style.transform = `rotate(${intialMinuteHandPosition}deg)`;
    secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${intialSecondHandPosition}deg)`;

    function timer(){
        hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${intialHourHandPosition+=(30/3600)}deg)`;
        minuteHand.style.transform = `rotate(${intialMinuteHandPosition+=(6/60)}deg)`;
        secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${intialSecondHandPosition+=6}deg)`;
    }
    setTimeout(()=>{secondHand.style.transition = 'transform 1s linear';
                    hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${intialHourHandPosition+=(30/3600)}deg)`;
                    minuteHand.style.transform = `rotate(${intialMinuteHandPosition+=(6/60)}deg)`;
                    secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${intialSecondHandPosition+=6}deg)`;
                    },0)
        
    setInterval(timer,1000)
```

```css
*{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.clockContainer{
    top: 20%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 350px;
    margin:auto;
    position: relative;
}
.clockContainer img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.handHolder{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-40%);
}
.hour{
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: black;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform-origin: 0%;
    border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
}
.minute{
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform-origin: 0%;
    border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;

}
.second{
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 30%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform-origin: 0%;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>

    <div class="clockContainer">
        <img src="clock.jpg" >
        <div class="handHolder"></div>
        <div class="hour"></div>
        <div class="minute"></div>
        <div class="second"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you mean? I don't see any difference in behavior between edge and chrome.

Comment: after loading, the secods Hand pushed by 6deg with 1sec linear transiition. then it should repeat the same thing again and again. but after the first 6deg transition it gets back to the initial position then quickly move to the last position and after then it behaves as expected. what is wiered is the first two seconds behaviour, cann't figure it out why this is happening. but as i told earlier it works fine with edge